# Is root required for screen sharing / remote desktop on Android Pi

Tags: 9.0-pie, remote-access

I am having inordinate difficulty trying to get any kind of remote desktop working on a Samsung SM-T510 tablet I have just bought (which runs on Android Pi).   I have tried Teamviewer, Airdroid and Vysor - and none allow me to do anything meaningful.   (I have enabled Developer Mode).

I have tentatively concluded that something in the Android permissions model is preventing this sharing from happening, which would seem to mean that looking to do this without jailbreaking the phone [ which I don't want to do ] is futile.

**Does anyone know if it is actually possible to do screen sharing on Android Pi on a phone that is not rooted?**

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy?

Comment: @trishmapow Thank you for this link - unfortunately it does not answer my question, and, indeed installing this piece of software seems stupidly hard (the instructions for Ubuntu 16.04 dont match reality, and the snap does not work).   I'm loathe to download a gig of data for an SDK I'm told is not needed to compile the runtime, but then required when I attempt to compile it!